# Count down timer transfer to another page

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to do:

When this timer hits 00 on min's and 00 on sec's i want it to transfer the user to another page... I am just starting with code so please go easy on me if im trying to do something stupid...

This is the Index:

```
<p>Here you can place what you would like the heading to be</p>

<script src="countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
        year: 2014,
        month: 5, 
        day: 12,
        hour: 10,
        minute: 56,
        width: 300, 
        height: 50
    });
</script>
```

There is also a countdown.js

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6hp8g7odq2otg3/countdown.js

Comment: There's no info on how to do this on the documentation for this script?

Comment: None that i found unless i missed something?

Comment: The code is not documented and highly obfuscated so it's nearly impossible to find how it works and change it to what you want. Either ask whoever wrote the code, or find other countdown code that also supports a callback function when it finish the countdown.

Comment: Do you know of anyplaces that i could get another countdown timer that works the same way as this? But can do what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out how the countdown works. Answer already provided to Asker but thought it should also be placed here for reference:

```
var timer = new Countdown({
    year: 2014,
    month: 5,
    day: 12,
    hour: 10,
    minute: 56,
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    onComplete: onTimerComplete
});

function onTimerComplete()
{
    // perform action
}
```

Countdown calls the function onTimerComplete once it has finished.

Comment: Is there any possibility you can edit this in to the code? As i have never ever worked with a time stamp so i am clueless as to what you mean.

Comment: I tried to look through the countdown.js file and that was the only thing I could find before all the characters started merging together.

Comment: Could i chat with you over email? It would be a bit easier i would like to ask a few things... If you have time that is.

Comment: I'm in school atm, I edited my answer with a possible solution, its untested so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: Thanks for that... Im only just starting with code so excuse all the questions that i would like to ask.

Comment: Email me: columferry.help@gmail.com, with html, jquery, php related questions. I'm ok with javascript, not great though